# How do I call a c# method without having the page reload?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp:LinkButton in a bootstrap modal that I want to use to call a method that I have in my c# code that sends a SOAP request to a remote server, and then displays the data in a new modal.  The problem is that when I click the button, the page reloads closing the first modal and preventing the second modal from popping up.  How can I call my c# method without having the page reload?

Asp Button Code:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnLMILink" OnClick="btnLogMeIn_ServerClick" OnClientClick="return false" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm">click</asp:LinkButton>
```

C# method that the button is calling

```
protected void btnLogMeIn_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string lmiDivHTMLStart = "<div class=\"form-group\">";
        StringBuilder lmiDivHTMLMiddle = new StringBuilder();
        string lmiDivHTMLEnd = "</div>";
        List<string> lmiData = new List<string>();
        lmiData = GetLMIData();

        foreach(string str in lmiData)
        {
            lmiDivHTMLMiddle.Append("<label>"+str+"</label>");
        }

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showLMIModal();", true);
        LMI_Div.InnerHtml = lmiDivHTMLStart + lmiDivHTMLMiddle + lmiDivHTMLEnd;
    }
```

And just in case it helps here is my SOAP request:

```
protected List<string> GetLMIData()
    {
        string url = "fake url";
        string companyID = "123456";
        string password = "fake password";
        string encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(companyID + ":" + password));
        List<string> lmiData = new List<string>();
        string currentLine = "";

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAP:Action");
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=\"utf-8\"";
        webRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("web request created");

        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("inside of try");
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("reader and data stream created");
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("inside of while");
                currentLine = reader.ReadLine();              
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("end of while");
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (HttpException ex)
        {

        }
        lmiData = SplitString(currentLine);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("end of method");
        return lmiData;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: A page load will always be needed to call a C# method, Or you must make an ajax call to an endpoint.

Comment: @AntoOne OP is _not_ using `MVC` - re: `<asp:LinkButton....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use AJAX and a WebMethod/Web Service for solving your requirement. In order to address current situation you have to do following changes:

1. Replace your server side LinkButton "btnLMILink" to a normal  anchor tag (non server side)
2. Create a WebMethod and place your "btnLogMeIn_ServerClick" code in it
3. Make an AJAX call to the WebMethod on  anchor tag click

Now here is the explanation:

1. Replace LinkButton

From this:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnLMILink" OnClick="btnLogMeIn_ServerClick" OnClientClick="return false" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm">click</asp:LinkButton>
```

To this:

```
<a id="btnLMILink" href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary">btnLMILink</a>
```

2. Create a WebMethod

I have made a WebMethod named "PostMessage" and placed your "btnLogMeIn_ServerClick" code in it. Name it what ever you want to. I am putting static data in "lmiData" list; you can make call to SOAP method there.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string PostMessage()
{
    var lmiDivHTMLStart = "<div class='form-group'>";
    var lmiDivHTMLMiddle = new StringBuilder();
    var lmiDivHTMLEnd = "</div>";
    var lmiData = new List<string>() { "Apple", "Android", "Mango", "Orange" }; // call SOAP method here

    foreach (string str in lmiData)
    {
        lmiDivHTMLMiddle.Append("<label>" + str + "</label>");
    }

    return lmiDivHTMLStart + lmiDivHTMLMiddle + lmiDivHTMLEnd;
}
```

3. Make an AJAX call

Second modal, I named it "soapModal"

```
<div class="modal fade" id="soapModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal-label">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal-label">Second Modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

AJAX method calling WebMethod "PostMessage". Here I have a page named "Default.aspx" where my WebMethod is present, you can give URL according to your page and path.

```
<script>

    $(function () {
        $('#btnLMILink').on('click', function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Default.aspx/PostMessage',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify({}),
                beforeSend: function () {
                    console.log('sending'); // show loader or something
                },
                success: function (result) {                        
                    $('#soapModal .modal-body').empty();
                    $('#soapModal .modal-body').append(result.d);
                    $('#soapModal').modal('show');
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    console.log('error');   // show error if not able to call WebMethod
                }
            });

        });
    });

</script>
```

I assume you have jQuery in your project.

Hope it helps